# Insert 1 Million Records in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, phpmyadmin

I have a simple table 'MyCombs' with 3 columns. ID, Start & End. ID is autoincrement so I have no problem with that. For Start & End points, I have 1million records. These records are different. I have created Insert queries for these 1 miilion records. Now i am facing a problem. When i try to simply run the queries by copying 50,000 records each time in phpMyAdmin, it does not insert these records in table. Loading, Loading. I saw some solution where we have to create a sql format file. I tried but was not able to create such file. Fairly saying, i am completely new to this. Is there anyway i can insert these records into table??

Comment: insert into select pattern ? No reason to go out to csv and in again.  [Example 4 and 5](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/11/mysql-insert-command/)

Comment: Are you trying to insert records from an php application ? What is the database ? Is it MySQL or what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by using `'Bulk Insert'` either in MySql or SqlServer !!!

For More Information...refer the following link..

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html